# How to solve double jumping

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've followed the Unity tutorial for "Roll-A-Ball", and have added some extensions. The ball can now jump, but it jumps too many times each jump; I just want the ball once at a time when I press on SPACE. Now I can press on SPACE 3 times an it'll jump higher and higher.

```
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Vector3 jump = new Vector3(0.0f, 150.0f, 0.0f);

            rb.AddForce(jump);
        }
```

EDIT:

Have tried changing the code a little bit, but now I can ONLY jump once (the first time)

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
      if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && jump.y <= 0.0f)
    {
        jump.Set(0.0f, 150f, 0.0f);
        rb.AddForce(jump);

     }
    }
```

Comment: You are getting this result because each time you are pressing space you are adding additional force to the ball. 3 presses == 3 * force in direction. Monitor the upward velocity of the ball and only add the force when a certain parameter is met. ie if upward velocity <= 0, then you can jump! Anything else, you can't.

Comment: have tried to do that but it doesn't work :(

Comment: @adadudu Weird. It should be available again once the Z velocity meets `0.0f` in the air, which means in the mid of the trajectory -- that is, unless I'm wrong and I know nothing about UnityScript. Try logging the velocity whenever Spacebar is pressed to make sure that you aren't missing anything :^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. The solution is to add `OnCollisionEnter` where you can handle what will happen when the player collides with the ground. Furthermore I've added a counter which is set to 0 when the player jumps and 0 again when he collides with the ground.

The counter:

```
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        if (JumpCount < 1)
        {
            Vector3 jump = new Vector3(0.0f, 250.0f, 0.0f);
            rb.AddForce(jump);
            JumpCount++;
        } 
    }
```

The counter is set to 0 here:

```
 void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    JumpCount = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This can get a bit hard to follow (since it's not a step-by-step tutorial, but rather a scheme).

You must check for when the ball reaches the floor checking if the velocity ever gets at 0 or above after the first press. Once it does, then set some bool (here named `CanJump`) to `true` (or whatever your language defines for true).

There is some more checking to do as well; once CanJump is set to true (because your velocity is now `>= 0`), set also an int variable called `NumJumps` to 0. And increment it each jump. This way you can set `CanJump` to false after two jumps, which prevents the ball from jumping.

Please note I know nothing about Unity 3D, but I have a bunch of experience with 3D games (like Unreal Engine 1 and thus UT99 modding).

Comment: This is a good answer and will work with Unity. Another check you could do is that `onCollisionEnter` with the 'floor', set `canJump` to true, and then `onCollisionrExit` `canJump` would become false.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the best solution is to use a Raycast.

```
bool isOnGround = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, 1.875f);
```

Replace 1.875f with the distance between your character's origin and the ground, plus a little bit extra. Then, you can check for `isOnGround` when deciding whether a jump should happen or not.